# Dlookup as Control Source for textbox in Navigation Subform

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have looked for answers and I have shuffled around every variably, quotation mark, form reference, everything that I can think of to get this DLookup to work. Here's the background information on what I'm trying to do here:

PrimaryRouteID = short text data (key player in this lookup)

SignSumtxt & SqFtSumtxt = textboxes where I want my DLookup values to show (via changing the control source in VBA)

PrimaryRoadInventoryTotals = The query that has the pertinent information that I want

PrimaryRoadInventoryMaster = Form nested in Navigation form (main form to use)

The rest I'll explain here: I'm designing a DLookup function that finds a quantity on the PrimaryRoad InventoryTotals query using the PrimaryRouteID taken from a textbox on a form that is nested in a Navigation form. This DLookup functions within the form by itself, but I've been struggling to fix it to work within the Navigation form.

It's my understanding that since I have put the MasterForm in the NavForm, it is now nested in the NavSubform, and you have to reference values inside the NavSubform, not just the form that you're working in. I seem to have figured out the correct syntax (I think) to grab the value I want, but my DLookup still does not function like it needs to. In the version below, both textboxes that have DLookups assigned to them have #Name? errors. I cannot for the life of me figure out what to do!

The Code (separated for easier viewing):

```
Private Sub RouteSelectCombo_AfterUpdate()
SignSumtxt.ControlSource = DLookup("[TotalQuantity]", "[PrimaryRoadInventoryTotals]", "[PrimaryRoadInventoryTotals]![PrimaryRouteID] ='" & [Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].Form![PrimaryRouteIDtxt] & "'")

SqftSumtxt.ControlSource = DLookup("[TotalSqFt]", "[PrimaryRoadInventoryTotals]", "[PrimaryRoadInventoryTotals]![PrimaryRouteID] ='" & [Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].Form![PrimaryRouteIDtxt] & "'")
End Sub
```

One weird thing that I noticed, and what might be an indicator of what's wrong here, is that when I nest this code into a msgbox, it'll read "true" or "false." Don't know if that helps, but figured I'd mention it.

I appreciate it!

Comment: This question is *really* confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I've re-read your question, and whatever it is that you're trying to do, you need to find a way to do it *simpler.* `#Name?` just means that you got your bindings wrong, but there's too little relevant information and too much irrelevant information here to connect the dots.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is get Dlookup to grab a value from a query based on a textbox value on a form that's inside a nav form. I tried to make it sound clear but I guess it didn't work out that way. What more relevant information could I provide?

Comment: Break this into pieces, and you might have a fighting chance.  Get a reference to the nav form.  Get the textbox from that reference.  Get the value from the textbox.  Run the query using that value.  Obtain the desired data from the query result. Wrap all that in a custom lookup function and return the resulting data.

Comment: So rather than a complex DLookup, make a function that changes the criteria of the query based on that textbox value, then just lookup that resulting, filtered value?

Comment: I could be wrong here, but `[PrimaryRoadInventoryTotals]![PrimaryRouteID] =` is not a column reference, although it should be. I believe it should instead read: `"PrimaryRouteID =`

Comment: Doesn't change anything by taking away the query reference, unfortunately

Comment: Hmm... in your quesion you mention that `PrimaryRouteID` is your text field, but in the code its listed as `PrimaryRouteIDtxt`. If you set `[Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].Form![PrimaryRouteIDtxt]` to a text holder / msgbox, what do you get?

Comment: @Jiggles32 The PrimaryRouteID is a field in the query I'm pulling data from. The PrimaryRouteIDtxt is the textbox on the PrimaryRouteMaster form to which I am trying to get the data to show up in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to come back to this question and give some closure on the topic. While I wasn't successful in the methods presented here (and I'm sure I wasn't implementing them correctly), I ended up taking the route of simplicity (per Robert Harvey's suggestion) over forcing what I thought to be the best way to set up the Navigation form, and instead just make a form that has buttons which lead to the other forms that are to be used.

This way, I don't have to do any sort of crazy subform within a form within a nav form referencing, and I don't have a bunch of tabs on my Navigation form.

Thanks everyone for your help and answers!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign a value to a control, use the `.Value` property, not the `.ControlSource` property. The `.ControlSource` property takes a string control source, and that should start with `=` if you're using an expression.

If you actually want to assign the control source, you could either add `"=" &` at the start, but that's really bad design. The control source should not be variable.

What you probably should do:

```
Private Sub RouteSelectCombo_AfterUpdate()
    SignSumtxt.Value= DLookup("[TotalQuantity]", "[PrimaryRoadInventoryTotals]", "[PrimaryRoadInventoryTotals]![PrimaryRouteID] ='" & [Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].Form![PrimaryRouteIDtxt] & "'")

    SqftSumtxt.Value= DLookup("[TotalSqFt]", "[PrimaryRoadInventoryTotals]", "[PrimaryRoadInventoryTotals]![PrimaryRouteID] ='" & [Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].Form![PrimaryRouteIDtxt] & "'")
End Sub
```

If you actually want to use it as a control source:

```
Private Sub RouteSelectCombo_AfterUpdate()
    SignSumtxt.ControlSource = "=DLookup(""[TotalQuantity]"", ""[PrimaryRoadInventoryTotals]"", ""[PrimaryRoadInventoryTotals]![PrimaryRouteID] ='"" & [Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].Form![PrimaryRouteIDtxt] & ""'"")"

    SqftSumtxt.ControlSource = "=DLookup(""[TotalSqFt]"", ""[PrimaryRoadInventoryTotals]"", ""[PrimaryRoadInventoryTotals]![PrimaryRouteID] ='"" & [Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].Form![PrimaryRouteIDtxt] & ""'"")"
End Sub
```